# Eclipse Maven Issue Showing missing

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, pom.xml

Showing missing jars but the jars are present in m2 folder:

[image: showing missing jars but the jars are present in m2 folder]

Project structure:

[image: project structure]

Tried deleting m2 folder and updating maven project but not working.

Comment: what happens when you run `mvn compile` in the terminal?

Comment: The pom.xml has an error marker - try fixing whatever that problem is.